# different sql query result on local/server for identical database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing an issue where for the same query on identical databases, receiving different results on local vs remote server.

Query is join on 3 separate tables, first (line_stations) should be the base with data filtered by second (teams), and then to show counted inputs from third (lista) with certain criteria in place, but also to show zeros if there are no counted inputs.

```
SELECT
  line_stations.*,
  COUNT(lista.position)
FROM
  lista
RIGHT JOIN
  (
    line_stations
  INNER JOIN
    teams ON line_stations.line = teams.line
  ) ON(
    lista.position= line_stations.position
  )
WHERE
  (
    line_stations.zone = 'Ruting' AND teams.team= 'V526-1' AND lista.team = 'V526-1' AND lista.input_date = '2020-06-08'
  ) OR(
    line_stations.zone = 'Ruting' AND teams.team = 'V526-1' AND lista.input_date IS NULL
  )
GROUP BY
  line_stations.position
ORDER BY
  line_stations.sort_no
```

The result I am getting for local server is good and as expected (even tho the code may be a little chunky) but on remote, I am receiving only partial data.

[local result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6hsK.png)

[remote result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gksV.png)

Comment: try to avoid screenshots and include its content directly in your question

Comment: You clearly have different data on the two servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and thank you for your answers, I managed to fix it by rearranging my query and restructured data to include only two tables, and now it works.

Data from table "teams" that I used for filter only, i merged with "line_stations"

```
    SELECT
  line_stations.position,
  line_stations.operators_no,
  COUNT(lista.position)
FROM
  line_stations
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  lista ON line_stations.position = lista.position AND lista.input_date = '2020-06-08'  AND lista.tim = 'V526-1'
  WHERE line_stations.zone = 'Ruting' AND line_stations.team LIKE '%V526-1%'
GROUP BY
  line_stations.position
 ORDER BY
  line_stations.sort_no
```

And this is my new table structure, with team values transferred from "teams" table.

```
line_stations
    |sort_no|line|team                       |position|zone  |operators_no|
    |36     |526 |V526-1;V526-2;V526-3;V526-4|USW 5   |Kiting|1
    |37     |526 |V526-1;V526-2;V526-3;V526-4|POST 1  |Ruting|1
    |38     |526 |V526-1;V526-2;V526-3;V526-4|POST 2  |Ruting|3
    |39     |526 |V526-1;V526-2;V526-3;V526-4|POST 3  |Ruting|2

lista
|team  |input_date|position|
|V526-2|2020-06-08|POST 20 |
|V542-1|2020-06-08|POST 33 |
|V542-1|2020-06-08|POST 30 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `group by linestations.position`, but have `linestations.*`.

That means that -- under most circumstances -- your query is malformed SQL.  What values should be in the columns that are not aggregated?

MySQL *happens* to support this in older versions, with the caveat that the values come from arbitrary rows -- and those rows can change from row to row or in your case from server to server.

It is rather unclear what you are actually trying to do.  However, with the construct you are using, it is not surprising that the results are inconsistent.  You can ask a new question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

You can set the parameters `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` so MySQL behaves like other databases in rejecting such a query.  This is now the default for the more recent versions of MySQL.

Comment: Hi, I am already receiving desired result (unfortunately posted as link screenshot) but only on local server, while on remote the data is also good but limited to couple results and not complete list. "line_stations" should consist all columns from it, wit the last one being counted values from "list"

Comment: @Дробац . . . Your local server is returning *arbitrary* results that happen to look right.  That does not mean that the query is unambiguous.  It is a shame that older versions of MySQL allowed this.

Comment: I don't think this explains the different number of rows. Also the query might be fine, if `line_stations.position` is PK (or a candidate).